# Add new KOMAoptions to customize .lco file?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I want to create extra KOMAoptions to be able to customize my `scrlttr2` style.

Should I create a .cls file or create an .lco file? Everything I was able to find online it is recommended to use an .lco file. However, with a .cls file I could easily pass my options to when using `\documentclass`. How do I do the same with an .lco file?

Can I create additional KOMAoptions that I can then set in my .tex file and check for in the .lco file?

To make the question more concrete:
I want to be able to set the option to add a stamp in my letter and whether to set display the bank information in the footer or not. `koma-script` uses the same kind of setting by the KOMAoptions. So I was thinking about creating new KOMAoptions and be able to check them in my .lco file to decide whether for this .tex file the banking information should be shown or not.

Comment: This is an abstract question and thus difficult to answer. `\KOMAoptions{textcolor=red}` may render all text red, but in reality the code is not about KOMAscript, but some color commands of a certain package (xcolor, color, whatever). The whole idea of an advanced documentclass is to replace the legacy classes of LaTeX, but not to replace all the packages. Focus your question.

Comment: @KeksDose: I have added more explanations to the question.

Comment: Why don't you simply write a `bank.lco`? Load it and its there, don't load it and no bank. However, I'm out for today. Usually a MWE is a good idea here.

Comment: AFAIK, you should not use `\KOMAoptions` for your own options. It is recommended to use, e.g., `\FamilyOptions` for custom packages or classes, as shown in section 12.2 of the KOMA-Script manuals. The family `KOMA` and therefore `\KOMAoptions` is reserved for KOMA. Alternatively there are many other packages for key-value options.

Comment: See, e.g., [this example for a CI lco](https://github.com/komascript/notepaper-wsu) in the [KOMA-Script wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/_list/wiki). It is also available in German. It does not only explain how to implement a corporate identity but also how to define new options. It is one of the largest and best explained examples I know.

Comment: BTW: I do not think, that you really need an option for this. Just test if the corresponding variable is empty. So setting an empty content would be enough to not print the bank. But this is only an opinion. Maybe you have reasons, I do not know.